# Maximal Smallest Number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Ran into a interesting problem which I have no idea how to solve but have the desire to.

> Let a and b be two positive real numbers and let $m$(a,b) be the smallest of the three numbers $a,$ $1/b$ and $1/a + b.$ For which pairs (a,b) is $m$(a,b) maximal? Prove!

Answer (score 2):

It is not too hard to see that the maximum can only occur for $a=\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{a}+b$.

Suppose for instance that $a<\min(\frac{1}{b},b+\frac{1}{a})$, then we can increase $a$ a little and improve our $m(a,b)$.
For $\frac{1}{b}$ and $b+\frac{1}{a}$ similar things happen.

Thus $a=\frac{1}{b} = b+\frac{1}{a}$ implies $a = \sqrt{2}$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}$.

Checking the answer is quite easy:

Suppose that $m(a,b)>\sqrt{2}$, then $a>\sqrt{2}$ and $\frac{1}{b}>\sqrt{2}$. But then $\frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}$ and $b<\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}$, so $b+\frac{1}{a}<\sqrt{2}$. A contradiction.

Thus $m(a,b)\leq\sqrt{2}$ for all $a$ and $b$. We already know that $m(\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$, thus this is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

First step: Suppose $m(a,b)\ge 2$.  Then $a \ge 2$ and $\frac 1b \ge 2$.  But then $\frac 1a \le \frac 12$ and $b\le \frac 12$, so $\frac 1a + b \le 1$.  Hence $m(a,b)\ge 2$ is impossible.

Second step: $a=b=1$ has $m(a,b)=\min(1,1,2)=1$, so $m(a,b)=1$ is possible.